# Change color of checkbox/checkbutton and entry box backgound and textpygtk2

Tags: css, text, colors, background, pygtk

I'm using a treeview that I'm trying to customize to suite my requiments or how I would like it to look, I have most of the color changing working how I'd like using modify_base/modify_text and set_property('foreground',"dadada") or set_property('cell-backgound',"dadada").

My problem is that if I click an entry box in edit mode in the treeview it defaults back to the white background with black text for the cell I am editing and all checkbuttons/checkbooks are the same where as I would like to have this colored the same background and text color when not selected or when selected have it all the same as the selected background color.

I am unsure if any of this is possible but if it is does anyone have any pointers or can anyone point me to sites to get a clue from, all my hunting so far has come up with nothing but or code or questions I am unable to answer.

I have also discovered "css" but am also unsure if this is feasible/possible, but if it is possible this way I guess I'll have to study up on "css" and how to program it.

Or for the checkbutton/checkbox would I be better to use images and change between the 2 somehow with a hidden checkbutton/checkbox column?

I feel that opinion is not really great as if the colors change, new images would need to be created tomatch the changes if this goes to other people.

I'm running pygtk2/python 2 with "glade 3.8.0".

I can attach my sample code if needed once I clean it up a bit, but I'm no programmer so it may be hard to understand, but works how I felt it should.

Thanks to anyone with pointers or help.

William.